# Function pointer with undetermined parameter

Tags: c, function-pointers

I want to have a function pointer that can take various types of parameters. How do I do that?

The following example (line 1), I want `void (*fp)(int)` to be able to take `void (*fp)(char*)` as well. The following code does not properly compile because I'm passing char* where int is expected so compiling the following code will give you warnings (and won't work properly).

```
void callIt(void (*fp)(int))
{
    (*fp)(5);
}

void intPrint(int x)
{
    printf("%d\n", x);
}

void stringPrint(char *s)
{
    printf("%s\n", s);
}

int main()
{
    void (*fp1)(int) = intPrint;
    callIt(fp1);
    void (*fp2)(char*) = stringPrint;
    callIt(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

Note: I know that attempting to pass integer 5 as char* parameter is stupid, but that's not the concern for this question. If you want, you can replace char* with float.

Comment: You aren't going to get exactly what you want in C.  You could do it in C++ with templates.  In C, you'll need to have different callIt functions for different types.

Comment: How is `int(5)` a valid argument for `floatPrint(float f)` anyway? You would need a cast, but that won't work if you've erased the function pointer type through a cast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say use `void (*fp)(void*)`, then pass in pointers to your variables and cast them as void*.  It's pretty hacky, but it should work.

eg:

```
void callIt(void (*fp)(void*))
{
    int x = 5;
    (*fp)((void*)&x);
}
```

Comment: It's not ideal though.  You should really think about redesigning the program so you don't have to resort to such hacky methods. :)

Comment: Notice int x = 5 forces type to be int there :(

Comment: To make it less hacky, you could in theory use a struct which is a union of possible types, and pass a pointer to that in, plus a variable to show the data type.  More work and complicates the code, but would make it seem more of a 'proper' solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect the call to stringPrint to do exactly?

It looks as though if you do get this working, it's going to end up attempting to print the contents of memory location 5 as a string. Which I suspect is not what you want as it will crash and I suspect you were intending it to output '5'.

Note also that ... requires at least one named argument. Passing a void * and an abusive amount of casting will at least compile.

Answer (score 1):

Although not nice, the type of the function pointer does not really matter.

Just define it as

```
typedef void (*fp_t)(void * pv);
```

The only thing you have to make sure is that the way you call it matches the function you assigend to it.

```
int intFuncWithTwoDoubles(double d1, double d2);
char * pCharFuncWithIntAndPointer(int i, void * pv);

...

fp_t fp = NULL;

fp = intFuncWithTwoDoubles;
printf("%d", fp(0.0, 1.0));

fp = pCharFuncWithIntAndPointer;
printf("%s", fp(1, NULL));

...
```

Comment: I'm no C standard guru, but this is looks pretty hacky, is probably is undefined behavior, and I definitely love it for its complete disregard for type safety.  Basically, you're relying on the compiler arranging whatever arguments and return values you set up at the point of the call instead of using the type of the function pointer.  Did you actually try this? What warnings, errors, and/or results did it produce?

Comment: @KevinVermeer: Yes, look like a dirty hack. But: It works, although producing warnings regarding type mismatches when assigning the functions addesses to the pointer. But as far as my investigation showed it does **not** lead to undefined behavious (I'll try to dig out the standards regarding this later today).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make it a function pointer that accepts a void* parameter?

```
void(*fp)(void*)
```

This would take care of all possible pointer parameters. Now for data types you could either make one function pointer type for each or just for the functions that are going to be utilized with the function pointers, pass the data types as pointers and dereference them in the function's beginning. That's just an idea without knowing exactly what you want to do.