# Running different functions with different arguments- Function pointers

Tags: c, pointers

This is similar to the question in [Function pointer with undetermined paramater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562828/function-pointer-with-undetermined-paramater?rq=1) but when
I tried it ,I get a compile errors:

error: too many arguments to function 'accessVariant'

error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

I define this at the top of my C file:

```
typedef void (*callBackHandler)(void*);
callBackHandler accessVariant= NULL;
```

I have a call back registration function:

```
void registerCallbackHandler(callBackHandler ptr_reg_callback)
{
    if (ptr_reg_callback == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        accessVariant = ptr_reg_callback;
    }
}
```

Inside the code I check for some boolean ,and then I register a specific type of access function:

```
if (bool)
{
    registerCallbackHandler((callBackHandler)aRead16);
}
else
{
    registerCallbackHandler((callBackHandler)aRead32);
}
```

Each of aRead16 and aRead32 takes different kinds of arguments.

Then I make the call:
`(*accessVariant)( (void*)arg1,(void*) arg2, (void*)&value )`

Comment: Why not just declare `callBackHandler` correctly? `typedef void (*callBackHandler)(void *, void *, void *);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to force a square peg into a round hole, just use round pegs. Declare `callBackHandler` as

```
typedef void (*callbackHandler)(void *, void *, void *);
```

Your functions do not have an undetermined number of parameters. They have three parameters.

Note that you are still on thin ice because of the explicit `void*` casts. Remove them and fix your prototype accordingly.

**Added:** If the functions do not all have the exact same parameter lists (such as your example where the third parameter is sometimes a `uint16*` and sometimes a `uint32*`), then you need multiple typedefs and select one appropriately.

```
typedef void (*genericCallback)(void);
typedef void (*callbackUint32Uint16Pint16Ptr)(uint32, uint16, uint16 *);
typedef void (*callbackUint32Uint16Uint32Ptr)(uint32, uint16, uint32 *);

void aRead16(uint32, uint16, uint16 *);
void aRead32(uint32, uint16, uint32 *);

void registerCallbackHandler(genericCallback callback)
{
    if (callback == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        accessVariant = callback;
    }
}

void RegisterSomething()
{
    if (use_the_uint16_callback)
    {
        registerCallbackHandler((genericCallback)aRead16);
    }
    else
    {
        registerCallbackHandler((genericCallback)aRead32);
    }
}

void CallTheCallback()
{
    if (use_the_uint16_callback)
    {
        ((callbackVoidPtrVoidPtrUint16)accessVariant)(x, y, z16);
    }
    else
    {
        ((callbackVoidPtrVoidPtrUint32)accessVariant)(x, y, z32);
    }
}
```

This requires that `use_the_uint16_callback` remain unchanged for the duration of `accessVariant` since you must cast a function pointer back to its original type before using it.

**Updated** to change all the parameters. Previous version was based on incorrect information provided in comment. (First two parameters were initially claimed to be pointers, but in comment revealed that they are not. Third parameter was initially claimed to be a `uint16`, but in comment revealed that it is actually `uint16 *`.)

Comment: The third argument could possibly be uint16 or uint32.In addition,the implementation inside aRead16 and aRead32 is different.

Comment: Another question, just in case for the future,what if my functions take different number of parameters.How could that be solved? Thanks.

Comment: I can't prototype my read functions like you suggested. I get this error:  
`error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token.`
The compiler likes the way I used to have it before:  
 `boolean aRead16( uint32 baseAddress, uint16 offset, uint16 *data )`

Comment: I had to chunk the comments into 2 parts.

Now about calling part, I call it like this:    
`(  CALL_BACK_TYPE_CAST  accessVariant )
                  (  base_address,read_offset, &value )`
where `#define CALL_BACK_TYPE_CAST (callbackVoidPtrVoidPtrUint16)` for example in case the processor deals with 16 bits instead of 32.
With this I get : warning: passing argument 1 of 'accessVariant' makes pointer from integer without a cast.
Also I get  
`error: too many arguments to function 'accessVariant'`

Comment: The comment above passing argument was supposed to be for argument 3:  
  warning: passing argument 3 of 'accessVariant' makes pointer from integer without a cast.

Comment: You said that the third argument is `uint16` or `uint32`, but the case where you say you are having a problem is where the third argument is `uint16 *`. `uint16` and `uint16 *` are not the same thing. It sounds like you are having some more basic issues with the C programming language.

Comment: I understand the difference btw uint16 and uint16 *. It's just that when I typed the question, I used the awriteRead function signature which takes uint16 as the third argument. Sorry.

Comment: In which case you should have understood what the mismatch was that triggered the warning.

Comment: I call RegisterSomething() only once when I initialize the code.I'm not using CallTheCallback() to avoid doing the check for use_the_uint16_callback for every access. I use a #define to use the appropriate cast before accessVariant.It seems I might have to eventually use your CallTheCallback because I'm faced with another problem.Whenever I want to use aRead32, I would like arg1 ,which is the address, to be nibble shifted to the left compared to the arg1 passed to aRead16.